# Can't get JTextField value to Database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

In here `NewJLabel` is my Swing file and This is my main class to access everything
and I need to get value from text field to database.

This code compiles and runs but does not update in database.

I am using Netbeans and the connection between MySQL and Java is working.

```
public class Patient extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   NewJPanel patient=new NewJPanel();
    static Patient p=new Patient();

public static void main(String arg[]){
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new NewJPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        p.addregno();
       }
     });
}

 public void addregno(){
      JButton save=patient.getSave();
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {      
    JTextField reg= patient.getRegno();
    String s=reg.getText();
    System.out.println(s);
    int n=Integer.parseInt(s);

    try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hos", "root", "");
            Statement state=(Statement) con.createStatement();
            state.executeUpdate("insert into patient (regno) values ('"+n+"')");
    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
           Logger.getLogger(NewJPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
    }
});
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I changed it but it's not worked

Comment: Umm..  the idea wasn't to make it work, but to *find out why it is failing!*  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) **Always copy/paste error & exception output.**